# Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2' when import firebase-admin

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im trying to add the firebase-admin to my ReactJS project but I got this error msg Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2', this is my code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("../firebase/aguia.json");

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
databaseURL: "https://guiacar-api.firebaseio.com"
});
console.log(admin);
```

aguia.json :

```
{
"type": "service_account",
"project_id": "*********",
"private_key_id": "******************************",
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE  KEY-----\n********************\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
"client_email": "**********",
"client_id": "**********",
"auth_uri": "**********",
"token_uri": "**********",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "**********"
```

}

Comment: `firebase-admin` is meant to be run server-side in Node.js -- are you trying to run it in the browser?

Comment: yes, I do.. there is some way to create a user without automatic login and without firebase-admin?